# well-formness/schema of S-expressions

Tags: lisp, schema

I am looking for tools that check the well-formness/schema of S-expressions.

Are you aware of such tools ?

As precised by Paul Nathan, what I'm exactly looking for is a Schema validator for sexp.

Comment: That is a bit surprising that no schema exists to enable checks on sexp-based data representations.

Comment: A tool I wrote years ago checked for the balancedness of parens, which is about all you need. If you are thinking in terms of XML schemata, what's the point? the grammar is dead simple.

Comment: @Paul : you are talking about the concrete grammar of sexp, while I am talking about the abstract grammar of a 'language', represented by sexp. Imagine I define a new format based on S-expr, tagged with dedicated 'keywords' : how do I ensure that an actual s-expr respects this format ?

Comment: You're conflating syntax and semantics. Syntactically, it's checked with a parser, ie, context free grammar. A well-formed sexp is parsable.  The question regarding keywords is semantics; you appear to be looking for a sexpr schema & validator. I haven't run across one. I'd reckon people usually walk the sexp tree and use it; if it's correct, alles gut, if it's incorrect, it raises a condition. The LOOP macro is an example of this as applied to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that OP question is about replacing the XML technology stack with S-expressions and Lisp.

An idiomatic approach with S-expressions is to implement ad hoc validators and transformers, tailored for specific data formats. Since Lisps are nearly declarative (and they allow defining countless possible declarative languages on top of them) there is no need in a specialised, common solution like XML Schema or DTD.

Depending on the Lisp flavour you're using, you can choose a pattern matching library suitable for your needs. Embedded Prolog implementations (like Schelog) can help too.

Comment: The point of a schema is that it is more readable than code - I can immdiately see than foo.bar is not optional and that it must be an integer between 3 and 9.  With an ad-hoc validator this information will be incomprehensible to non-Lispers.

Answer (score -1):

S-expressions don't really have schemas, as such. Well-formed S-expressions in something approaching a normal grammar description conform to (very roughly):

```
atom := <character>+
sexp := atom | '(' sexp* ')'
```

That is, an S-exp is either a single atom or a list of zero or more S-expressions. Writing a validator for that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: It'd be good if whoever down-voted this could leave a comment indicating why.

Comment: You have expressed the equivalent of saying xml tags start with < and end with >, which is not at all the same as what DTDs do for XML.

Comment: @AlexBrown Well, S-expressions don't *have* schemas. S-expressions are pretty much a sequence of balanced parenthesised expressions.